# How to restore data from Userdefault or table view when the IOS app reopens

Tags: swift, xcode

I am developing an app that stores notification data and displays it on the table view of the app page. Whenever I receive an FCM notification, I store the data inside `UserDefaults.standard.array` and refresh the table view, and display it on it. However, when I close the app and reopen it, all the data on the table was gone? Is it because `UserDefaults.standard.array` doesn't restore data if the app reopens or because I did not refresh the table view correctly? My intuition is about the first guess because when I receive other notification and refresh the table view, the past data wasn't load. Here is part of my `appDelegate` that deals with the notification:

```
// Extention on Overiding Notification Center
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    
    if let notification = userInfo["aps"] {
        print("Alert: \(notification)")
    }
    
    guard
        let triggerID = userInfo["trigger_id"],
        let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
        let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
        let body = alert["body"] as? String,
        let date = userInfo["trigger_date"],
        let severity = userInfo["severity"],
        let time = userInfo["trigger_time"]
    else {
        // handle any error here
        print("error parsing notification")
        return
    }
    var triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
    let info = "\(body)=-=\(date) \(time)"
    triggers?.append(info)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(triggers, forKey: "triggers")
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    print(severity)
    if(severity as! String == "2"){
        print("higher severity!")
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
    }
    print(userInfo)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    
    // send post request to the API endpoint with the trigger that needs to be disabled
    let params: [String:Any] = ["trigger_id": triggerID]
    AF.request("http://vocation.cs.umd.edu/flask/api/disable_trigger", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            //print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))
            print("sending trigger id to server \(triggerID)")
        }
    
    
    //update tableview:
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppNotification"), object: "myObject", userInfo: userInfo)
    
    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.list, .sound]])
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
    // Print full message.
    guard
        let triggerID = userInfo["trigger_id"],
        let aps = userInfo[AnyHashable("aps")] as? NSDictionary,
        let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary,
        let body = alert["body"] as? String,
        let date = userInfo["trigger_date"],
        let severity = userInfo["severity"],
        let time = userInfo["trigger_time"]
    else {
        // handle any error here
        print("error parsing notification")
        return
    }
    var triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
    let info = "\(body)=-=\(date) \(time)"
    print(severity)
    triggers?.append(info)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(triggers, forKey: "triggers")
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
    //        if(severity > 1){
    //            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
    //        }
    print(userInfo)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    
    // send post request to the API endpoint with the trigger that needs to be disabled
    let params: [String:Any] = ["trigger_id": triggerID]
    AF.request("http://vocation.cs.umd.edu/flask/api/disable_trigger", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            //print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8))
            print("sending trigger id to server \(triggerID)")
        }
    
    //update tableview:
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppNotification"), object: "myObject", userInfo: userInfo)
    
    completionHandler()
    
  }
}
```

This is how my tableview page looks like:

```
class HomePageViewController: UIViewController {

// userName
@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
// description
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName")
let ladygaga = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "idCollection")



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                       forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    // notification create:
    userName.text = "Welcome! \(username ?? "")"
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appnotification), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppNotification"), object: nil)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
    {(granted, error) in
        // action
    }
    //
    center.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { settings in
        if(settings.authorizationStatus == .denied || settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined){
            self.createAlert(title: " Notification required",
                             message: "Your current notification is off, please turn it on in settings->IFTTT->Notification")
        }
    })
}

@objc func appnotification(notification: Notification) {
    //print(notification.userInfo ?? "")
    tableView.reloadData()
}


// function that create a alert window that notify users
func createAlert(title: String, message: String){
    let Alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    Alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) in
        //self.respondToAPI()
        Alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}

extension HomePageViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
// function to display trigger info
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
    let trigger = triggers![indexPath.row] as! String
    let listItems = trigger.components(separatedBy: "=-=")
    let message = "Message: \(listItems[0])\nDate: \(listItems[1])"
    self.createAlert(title: "Trigger Information", message: message)
}
// function that swipe to delte triggers
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // first delete data in that row
        var triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
        triggers?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(triggers, forKey: "triggers")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        // then delete that row on the table
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
  }
}


extension HomePageViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
    return triggers!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
-> UITableViewCell {
    let triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath)
    let trigger = triggers![indexPath.row] as! String
    let listItems = trigger.components(separatedBy: "=-=")
    cell.textLabel?.text = listItems[0]
    return cell
    
  }
}
```

Sorry for some messy style by the code block. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is quite confusing, using `UserDefaults` as data source is bad practice and unnecessary expensive.

As your saved array is `[String]` declare a datasource array

```
var triggers = [String]()
```

and declare two methods to load and save data from `UserDefaults`

```
func loadData() {
    self.triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers") as? [String] ?? []
}

func saveData() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(self.triggers, forKey: "triggers")
}
```

---

Populate the array once when the app launches

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    ....
    loadData()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

---

When a new notification arrives add it to `triggers` and save the data, replace

```
var triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
let info = "\(body)=-=\(date) \(time)"
triggers?.append(info)
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(triggers, forKey: "triggers")
```

with

```
let info = "\(body)=-=\(date) \(time)"
self.triggers.append(info)
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.saveData()
```

---

To delete an item remove it from the data source array and – again – just save the array

Replace

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // first delete data in that row
        var triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
        triggers?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(triggers, forKey: "triggers")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        // then delete that row on the table
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
  }
}
```

with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // first delete data in that row
        self.triggers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        saveData()
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
  }
}
```

---

In `cellForRow` don't load the array again and again, get the item from the data source array, replace

```
let triggers = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "triggers")
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath)
let trigger = triggers![indexPath.row] as! String
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell",for: indexPath)
let trigger = triggers[indexPath.row]
```

---

And `numberOfRows` is simply

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return triggers.count
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Careful and complete solution! I have a question, I am new to Swift, If I am defining the variable triggers and its functions(save and load), what class shall I add this variable in? appdelegate? And Is it possible that I could use this variable across classes? I am searching the global variable in Swift and they told me to UserDefault directly, do you mind explaining the globalness of this variable to me? Moreover, could you explain what is the key problem that I cannot load my data every time I reopen it? Again, thank you for your solution, I really appreciate your efforts

Comment: As the methods contain only one line respectively, I'd declare them in any controller you need it. Or extend `UIViewController`. Frankly I don't know why your code doesn't work, you should not use this approach anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I am processing the notification and add them into the array in appdelegate, and it seems what you wrote on the line self.tableview.reloaddata() doesn't quite work. Is there a way to adjust this? And after save the data, why you skip the  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() to synchronize the data update?

Comment: The data source array `triggers` must be declared in `HomePageViewController`. As you are passing the new trigger string in the `userInfo` dictionary of the custom notification move the entire logic to add the trigger into  `appnotification`. Or instead of the custom notification add a reference to `HomePageViewController` in `AppDelegate` and set it in `viewDidLoad`. Or use a (callback) closure. There are many ways.